# What does return alone does in C++?

Tags: c++, return-value

I've been reading an example about finding gcd, which is Greatest Common Divisor, but it uses return only in the following code. 
What's it that? Is it legal to use return like that?
I've searched about that and nothing seems to make me clear. Please..
 Here's the code:

```
void fraction::lowterms ()
{
    long tnum, tden, temp, gcd;// num  = numerator and den = denumator 
    tnum = labs (num);
    tden = labs (den);
    if ( tden == 0)
    {
        exit (-1);
    }
    else if ( tnum == 0)
    {
        num = 0;
        den = 1;
        return; //why return alone    used here???
    }
}
```

Comment: This... is a very dodgy function.

Comment: @Tartan: I think it's obvious there is supposed to be more code after that quoted. Hence your edit may be misleading.

Comment: `int gcd(int a, int b) { return (b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b)); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, nothing except terminate the function (which would have happened anyway)

The return type of this function is `void` meaning it does not return any value.

However, in general, the `return` statement stops the function, returns the value specified, then no further code in that function executes. In this case it was at the end of the function, so it adds nothing.

Comment: It would had the code even been valid. The missing `}` and a casual analysis of the function's logic suggests that there is more code to be found after that quoted.

Comment: Oh I see that now, would've helped if the original  code was formatted nicely :)

Comment: I wonder what return does in the context of assembly language or CPU instruction set. Does it `move` the returned value to a memory location and then sets the instruction register to the memory location after the function call?

Answer (score 4):

It ends execution of the function and returns control to the part of code that called the function.

There is no value after the `return` keyword, because the function has a return type of `void` and thus there is simply no value *to* return.

As explained in your C++ book!

Comment: Books? Who uses those old things?

Comment: @Alex: The OP, starting now.

Comment: @Alex: Also, grown-ups, and anyone who cares seriously about the efficient acquisition of knowledge/information.

Answer (score 1):

If you find it more comfortable, you can

```
 return void();
```

which is equivalent to `return;` which may look misleading at first glance.

Comment: If anything, `return void()` is "misleadinger"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you mean?

Comment: Precisely what I said.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll give you that seeing `void()` might be uncommon, but it can definitely be more verbose than simply `return`. YMVV, that's why I asked.

Comment: Yes, it's more verbose. I don't see how it's "more comfortable". Contrary to your claim my opinion is that it is _more_ "misleading", because it looks like (a) you are constructing a temporary of type `void`, which is impossible, and (b) you are returning a value, which you're not. Each to their own though I guess...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit About (b): remember what *void* as only function argument does in old C. Emptiness and void isn't always the same but because this question is about c++, i can understand your position ;)

Comment: @Youka: Yes, indeed, totally unrelated!

Comment: @Youka: I didn't even know this was c++, so thanks for that (although I agree with Lightness that it isn't exactly pretty). Was this also allowed in C? Or was this added in C++ to allow for function templates to return e.g. `T()` where `[T = void]`?

Comment: @JorenHeit Good question. After a quick test, I doesn't appear to work in C; I'd like a question where that's covered in detail.

Comment: @black What other details would you be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

return is mostly used to return back to your caller function. It won't execute the below instructions in your function.

Ex:

```
void disp()
{
    1.....
    2.....
    return
    3....
    4....
}
```

here it won't execute 3 and 4 isntructions.

Comment: You say "mostly". How else is it used?

Answer (score 0):

Every function returns to the caller (more exactly the command after the call) at the end, so there's always a return, even in a function with return type void (where the compiler appends `return;` to the body, the programmer doesn't have to care about it). With your manual inserted return you created another exit point for your function.